# Avoid Wallpaper being Stretch on Some Devices

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

Hello There I am totally new to Android Dev. and learning it to my own. I am learning to setup a home screen wallpaper, and I have been facing a problem that my wallpaper being stretch on some devices (not all).

The problem is strange, when I set the wallpaper from my app, closes my app and come to home  screen the wallpaper was not in stretched condition but suddenly within a blink of eye or a second it gets stretched on the screen or you can say it expands itself giving nearly half of the image on the screen!

---

### Code I am trying

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                      context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);                         

 int height = metrics.heightPixels;

 int width = metrics.widthPixels;

 Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                            (context.getResources(), id);

 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, width, height, true);

 WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
 wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
 wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
 wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.mainActivity, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Log.e("xxx",""+width+" & "+height);
```

---

I am facing this problem on some device and not on all of the devices!

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Would be great to know on which devices you face that problem and android version of them. Also would be great to have image itself in order to reproduce problem.

Comment: Huawei devices :(

Comment: can u post some more codes

Comment: what kind of some more code? this is all i have to set the wallpaper!

Comment: @JavaNerd you didn't answer my question

Comment: @Divers I have already answered your question "Huawei devices :(", They are Android 4.0+ that's what I could answer

Comment: Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: You are using [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) to set images in background without providing any option like (cropping and adjusting images). so my suggetion is, why don't you use Intent to send your bitmap to gallery app where you can crop your images and set it as wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to include dp(dots per inch ) in your width height calculation of bitmap?

Comment: how? i mean what are you trying to say?